# How to reverse the order of elements in media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs, left and right, but when screen is less than for example 500px then left div become bottom div and right div becomes top div, div first in DOM should displays as second and second div as first.

[image]

I use `display: flex`, then divs are reversed but displays inline and ignore 100% width. What is wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class='nav'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='left_bottom'>
            LEFT/BOTTOM
        </div>
        <div class='right_top'>
            RIGHT/TOP
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav{
    background-color: red;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.left_bottom{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
}
.right_top{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 66.66%;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .left_bottom{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .right_top{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    } 
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ejbgu785/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this, it should work the way you wanted. let me know any issues.**

```css
.nav{
    background-color: red;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.left_bottom{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
}
.right_top{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 66.66%;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 500px)
    {
        .left_bottom{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .right_top{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
    }
```

```html
    <div class='nav'>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='right_top'>
                RIGHT/TOP
            </div>  
          <div class='left_bottom'>
                LEFT/BOTTOM
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bejkrools/wL1jLhuz/) Why 100% width is ignore when display:flex?

Comment: The flex property specifies the length of the item, relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. thats why it ignores width 100%

Comment: Is there a way to force it?

Comment: What you want to achieve, tell me the scenario, definitely there is a way to do things in CSS the way we wanted :)

Comment: I want to the right div will be above the left div when @media is on. Look at image in my post, it shows what i want achieve ;-)

Comment: try the updated solution above, it will work. :)

Let me know any issues further

Comment: Did you seen JSFIDDLE from my first comment? I'm usint bootstrap too :-)

Comment: Yes, I know that you are using bootstrap, I have just made few changes in your code, thats y asking you to try the updated code that I have written above.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to use `flexbox` for all the layout (including desktop and mobile).

For desktop:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

For mobile (option 1):

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .container{
        flex-direction: column; /*display as column*/
    } 
    .left_bottom{
        order: 2; /*reorder to bottom*/
        width: 100%; /*make full width*/
    }
    .right_top{
        order: 1; /*reorder to top*/
        width: 100%; /*make full width*/
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9q7mu68/)**

For mobile (option 2):

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .container{
        flex-direction: column-reverse; /*column & reverse*/
    } 
    .left_bottom, .right_top{
        width: 100%; /*make full width*/
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t7kg1am/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right_top">RIGHT/TOP</div>
    <div class="left_bottom">LEFT/BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.left_bottom {
    padding:15px 0;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
}
.right_top {
    padding:15px 0;
    background-color: blue;
    float:right;
    width:66.66%;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .left_bottom,
    .right_top {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lddz/Ln0bq7eg/

Answer (score 1):

Apply a class of `order-first` to your red block, and in your CSS media query, apply something similar to this:

```
.order-first {
  order: 1;
}
```

...assuming that you are using flexbox CSS.